# Debugging background scripts in safari extension

Tags: safari-extension

I am working on a custom Safari extension and would like to debug the Background scripts. I am not certain how to do this? Ideally, if there was a way to step into the background scripts, that would be great. But when I try to step into a background call, the Safari debugger just steps to the next line. The console.log within the background scripts do not get printed to the console (This is the console I launched from right clicking a popover that is part of the extension and then hitting inspect).

Any help on this would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this comes useful for someone - I figured out a way to view console statements in the background scripts. Open the extension builder and click on Inspect Global Page. Go to the console tab and the console.log messages in the background scripts will be printed in that console.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question that asks about a different type of Safari extensions but I figured it could be helpful to add an updated answer now that Safari (v14) supports the Web Extensions API (similar to the API that all other major browsers use).

Debugging background scripts is now built into the Safari menu in the toolbar: "Develop" => "Web Extension Background Pages" => select your (enabled) extension. That should open the dev tools with all your background scripts where you can set breakpoints, check the network tab, etc..

[image: Safari menu screenshot]

As a side note, you can debug your extension's popup by opening it, right clicking the popup and clicking "Inspect Element".

Comment: If popup hides, you can open it in new tab. First, find out popup URL: open pop-up, right-click, select "Inspect", then in developer tools type `window.location.href` and press `Enter` (or `Return` in case of macOS) key on your keyboard. Copy-paste that URL in new tab and press `Enter` again to open standalone popup.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [Safari Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) to debug your Safari App Extension. There is a control to select the extension container at the lower-right corner of the console.

[image]